# Can you link related lists to mail merge objects

Tags: mail-merge

We are trying to create a MS word mail merge document and having an issue when trying to link related lists.  We are working with Contacts, Application (custom object) and Scholarships (custom object).  Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'having an issue'.  The more details the better so people can try to help you solve the problem.

Comment: We were successful in pulling information from Contacts and Application objects, but unable to pull in information from Scholarship information.  On the application screen, Scholarship is a related list.  Hope this helps.